# Sync Data(Table) between AOS & Retail POS

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

We have a requirement to download InventBatch Table (and some custom tables) to Retail POS databases, i am looking for a solution (preferably official) to achieve this, please point me about Microsoft article or if anyone have achieved this, please share the methodology.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do so, in AX, you have to add the table in location tables, do the mapping, and add it to your retail channel schema.

Then, in your Retail channel DB, you have to modify the SQL scirpt to create the new table. Then modify the SQL scripts on the right entities to handle the new table properly.

Then you have to handle it in your viewmodel, your model and then the layout.
A good start is here: https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn720788.aspx
Then follow the links.